# Finding N distinct factors of N in c

Tags: c, debugging, distinct, c99, factors

Need to find all distinct factors of N. and display it as : for e.g.;for N=6

4

1 2 3 6

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{ 
int N;
int count =0;
int j=0;
int arr[j];
scanf("%d",&N);


    for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
        if((N%i)==0){
            printf("%d\n",i);
        
            count++;
        }
    }

  printf("%d\n",count);
  for(j=0;j<count;j++){
  printf("%d ",arr[j]);
  }
  return 0;
  }
```

the expected output for N=40 is

8

1 2 4 5 8 10 20 40

but my code gives:

6

1 2 4 5 8 10

I am not able to figure out what is wrong with the code here.

edit: I mistyped the code, here is the edit.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int N,p;
int j=0;
int count=0;
int arr[N];

scanf("%d",&N);

 
for(int i=1;i<=N;i++){
    p=N%i;
    if(p==0){
        arr[j]=i;
        j++;
        count++;
    }
}
printf("%d\n",count);
for(j=0;j<count;j++){
    printf("%d ",arr[j]);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int arr[0];` why would you need an array capable of holding zero elements?

Comment: Also, you print `arr[j]` in the end loop but your arr has size 0. I think you mistyped something. Try reading your code once.

Comment: This isn't what I'm getting when I run your code. Also, why would you print the divisors before the number of them? It doesn't match the required format.

Comment: I had  mistyped the code...I have edited it now!

Comment: N isn't assigned until after you made the array. That's undefined behaviour.

Comment: Try moving the `int arr[N];` declaration to just after the `scanf` call.

Comment: Thank you...it shows the expected output now!!